# CRM Dynamics how to save a record automatically on close of a browser window

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a scenario where I enable a user to click on a ribbon button, upon that I open a URL and pass CRM Form data as parameters to the URL, in the opened URL website I read the parameters and do something with them,now my question is how can I save the CRM record automatically when the user closes the opened website URL, how can I establish a link between CRM form and the opened external website window. I am aware of JavaScript but can I us parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.save(); in the external website, is this possible. Please help

Comment: @Filburt I dont understand how this will solve my problem as my problem is that I want to auto save when external windows closes and not depend on user to save. Can you  perhaps elaborate maybe I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: I used the (unsupported) `Xrm.Internal.openDialog` which allows callback function with a dialog result from your window. This would allow to save your data upon closing your window. If you're interested I'll post an example.

Comment: @Filburt yes I am can you please sjow me an example.

Comment: @Filburt yes I am interested.  Can you please share the example

Answer (score 0):

An unsupported method is to use `Xrm.Internal.Dialog`

Your ribbon button script to call the external window:

```
var encodeUrlParameter = "?data=" + encodeURIComponent('&param1=foo&param2=baz')

var src = "$webresource:new_your_webpage.html" + encodeUrlParameter;

var DialogOptions = new Xrm.DialogOptions();
DialogOptions.width = 540;
DialogOptions.height = 305;

Xrm.Internal.openDialog(src, DialogOptions, null, null, function (dialogResult) {
    if (dialogResult != null) {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_foo").setValue(dialogResult);
        Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
    }
});
```

Your external window code to handle the "Okay, close" event:

```
function Okay() {
    // set your return value
    Mscrm.Utilities.setReturnValue("foo");

    try {
        closeWindow(true); // Close the dialog box
    }
    catch (e) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(e.message);
    }
}
```

Your external page still needs to reference the CRM global context:

```
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out now. Will mark your answer too.

Comment: As usual when dealing with unsupported methods, keep in mind that anything inside the `Xrm.Internal` namespace can change, break or disappear without warning